# What's the different between .proto and .prototxt file

Tags: protocol-buffers

In caffe project, there are both *.proto* file and *.prototxt* file.

From **Google Protocol Buffer** documentation, *.proto* file defines the protocol, so what about the *.prototxt*, is it defined in Google Protocol Buffer, what's the different between them?

Answer (score 18):

The `.proto` file is used to describe the structure (the 'protocol') of the data to be serialized. The protobuf compiler can turn this file into python/or C++/or Java code to serialize and deserialize data with that structure

For the `.prototxt` file. Looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), we can see that, there are two different formats for serialized data (textual or binary). The text format is human-readable and modifiable (and the corresponding files usually have the extension `.prototxt`), but it takes up a lot more space than the binary format.

Comment: I checked your link and there is nothing about prototxt, only proto

Comment: @KansaiRobot Welp, it has been three years. I guess things have changed. Anyway, if you want to look at the doc at that time. Just look at it in web-archive. Here is the link http://web-old.archive.org/web/20170710214406/https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview