# OpenCv with DNN

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I was going through this [Object Detection Using OpenCv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/) post. While going through I came across readNetFromCaffe function. I am not able to fully understand how this function is working. Please can someone shed some light on what is prototxt file ?

Answer (score 1):

You define model architecture in prototxt file.

A sample prototxt file looks like

```
layer {
  name: "LayerName"
  type: "Python"
  top: "TopBlobName"
  bottom: "BottomBlobName"
  python_param {
    module: "My_Custom_Layer_File"
    layer: "My_Custom_Layer_Class"
    param_str: '{"param1": 1,"param2":True, "param3":"some string"}'
  }
  include{
        phase: TRAIN
  }
}
```

You can more about prototxt [here](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231n/slides/2015/caffe_tutorial.pdf) and [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), [the difference between .proto and .prototxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125534/whats-the-different-between-proto-and-prototxt-file)