# Differences between .proto, .pb and .pbtxt

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

As explained in [their website](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), the Protocol Buffers (or Protobuf) is "used to serialize structured data". The definition of the data structure is done in a .proto file that can be compiled by *protoc* and turned into code (.cc/.h, .py, .java...) that can be imported to several languages to manipulate and serialize the data.

My understanding is that the .pb files contain that data in binary and the .pbtxt are an equivalent that contain it in ascii. Is that correct?

If so, why are .pbtxt so readable? I've found some with commentaries (https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking/subgraphs/hand_renderer_cpu.pbtxt).

Also, are .pb/.pbtxt enough to interpret the data? Or do you need their .proto?

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44126448/12169382. In my words, .proto is used to generate code, we use the generated code to create and edit data, finnaly we can serialize the data to .pb or .pbtext as you like.